# Camel Interceptor conflict with CXF Interceptor

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I am Using custom InterceptStrategy and it throws errors after SOAP response is success.

Error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: It is illegal to call getRequest() after complete() or any of the dispatch() methods has been called
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.getRequest(AsyncContextImpl.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.dispatch(AsyncContextImpl.java:153)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$SecurityContextAsyncContext.dispatch(HttpServlet3RequestFactory.java:291)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Servlet3ContinuationProvider$Servlet3Continuation.redispatch(Servlet3ContinuationProvider.java:125)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Servlet3ContinuationProvider$Servlet3Continuation.resume(Servlet3ContinuationProvider.java:131)

```
public class ApplicationLogStrategy implements InterceptStrategy {

    @Override
    public Processor wrapProcessorInInterceptors(CamelContext context, ProcessorDefinition<?> definition,
            Processor target, Processor nextTarget) throws Exception {


            return new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("Display" + definition);
                    if (definition.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(ApplicationConstants.INITIAL_LOG)) {
                        //setCommonFields(exchange);
                        //setSpecificFields(exchange);
                    }
                    target.process(exchange);

                }
            };

    }
}
```

My camel route:

```
 <camelContext id="id-por" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
      <!-- route starts from the cxf webservice -->
      <from uri="cxf:bean:porEndpoint" />
      <doTry>
        <to uri="bean:soapBean?method=processSOAP"/>
        <bean id="soap_success" method="processSuccess" ref="soapBean"/>
        <camel:bean id="published_log"  method="info('Message - SUCCESS')" ref="logger"/>
            <doCatch>
                <camel:exception>java.lang.Exception</camel:exception>
                <handled>
                    <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>
                <to uri="bean:soapBean?method=processGenericError"/>
        </doCatch>
      </doTry>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

It throws error after the message "Message - SUCCESS" is logged. :

```
<camel:bean id="published_log"  method="info('Message - SUCCESS')" ref="logger"/>
```

I added `<stop/>` but no luck, still throws the error : It is illegal to call getRequest() after complete() or any of the dispatch() methods

Comment: What are you trying to do and why are you using the intercept strategy in the first place - that is only really for advanced stuff and for some very special use-cases.

Comment: I have custom logging and I set partial payload data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `target.process(exchange);`

just `return target;`